# MKMapSnapshotter takes long time for creating Image

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapsnapshotter

I have a working MKMapSnapshotter in my **awakeWithContext** and i want to set its image for my imageView.

The problem is, that the MKMapSnapshotter is to slow and the image won't be set. Only one or two seconds later, it creates the snapshot image.

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    var finalImage = UIImage()
    var snapshotterEnd = MKMapSnapshotter()
    snapshotterEnd.startWithCompletionHandler(){snapshot, error in

        finalImage = snapshot.image
    }
    imageView.setImage(finalImage)
}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the completion handler itself will set the image.

```
snapshotterEnd.startWithCompletionHandler() { snapshot, error in
    imageView.setImage(snapshot.image)
}
```

The completion block is documented as running on the main thread so you don't need to use `dispatch_async` to run it there.

Comment: Great. Be sure to also handle the situation where you could be getting an error, or the app will crash at that point (because you're behaving as if `snapshot` is not `nil`, which it will be).

Comment: According to the Apple docs the completion block is already on the main thread, so you don't need the `dispatch_async()`.